# MySQL import from stdin

Tags: mysql, bash, awk

I am generating a csv in stdout using awk. 
Is there a way to directly import that contents in mysql without putting it to file?

Answer (score 12):

As the answer from @xdazz says, just use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. I assume it was downvoted out of ignorance or lazyness. A quick perusal of the MySQL manuals would have shown that to be a perfectly viable answer.

In 2016 and for MariaDB, which will be most relevant to most users, you do this:

`bash
awk '{ /* My script that spits out a CSV */ }' | mysql --local-infile=1 -u user -ppassword mydatabase -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/dev/stdin' INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"';"`

Obviously, do bother to read the manual and change the options to `LOAD DATA INFILE` as required to suit your specific case.

Comment: how to do this in Windows system?

Answer (score 4):

MySQL supports getting data in via extended inserts that look like this:

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values
(a,b,c),
(d,e,f),
(g,h,i);
```

So you can modify your CSV to include a left paren and a right paren and a comma, and prepend it with `insert into table...` and append it with a semicolon, then you can pipe that directly to a MySQL commandline.

You can also use named pipes, a Unix construct, to pipe a TSV (tab-separated, not comma-separated) to a `load data infile` like this:

```
mkfifo /tmp/mysqltsv
cat file.csv | sed -e 's/,/\t/g' > /tmp/mysqltsv
mysql -e "load data infile '/tmp/mysqltsv' into table tblname"
```

That is pseudocode. You need to run the cat in one process and the mysql command in another. Easiest is to use two different terminals. More advanced is to background the `cat|sed`.

Answer (score 2):

It does not seem that you can import CSV from stdin directly.
You have to save it to a file so that mysql uses its name as the name of the table (without the extension), you can use mysqlimport as in:

`mysqlimport -uUSER -pPASS DB FILE`

Comment: Here we have the closest thing to a proper answer, with zero upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

@xdazz was quicker than me, but I would consider putting the result to a file. Why? Because that way, if something went wrong, you can check and track the issue back. This would be very helpful, if you face intermittent problems, that don't always occur. Of course, to preserve disk space, after the import is done, I'd ZIP them up not to consume too much.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, just use pipe.

<del>$ your_command | mysql -u user -p</del>

*Sorry, this answer is not enough. You can't pipe the csv out direct to mysql.
You have to do extra work to make the result be valid sql.*

Or, you may consider using mysql native `load data infile` syntax which is supporting loading a csv file to database.

Comment: Why was this answer given? It doesn't work. Why is it being upvoted? IT DOESN'T WORK. Try it. You'll get a syntax error. This only works if the output of "your_command" is valid SQL, which a CSV most certainly is not.

Comment: @xdazz I'm stunned that someone who posts an answer like this was able to amass 101k reputation, unless they made a honest mistake by not reading the question properly. Maybe it's time to edit this answer?